# Upload AJAX with input text and input file in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, web

In the JS site in have to send an ajax containing an input file to upload AND input texts

```
var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("id",$('#id').val());
    formdata.append("upload_url",$('#upload_url').val());
    formdata.append("type",$('#type').val());
    formdata.append("file",$('#upload').prop('files')[0]);
    formdata.append("label",$('#label').val());
    formdata.append("filter_from",$('#filter_from').val());
    formdata.append("filter_to",$('#filter_to').val());
    formdata.append("zone_geographique",$('#zone_geographique').val());
    formdata.append("actif",$('#actif').val());
    formdata.append("leafs",$('#affectedLeafs').val());
    $.ajax({
        url: 'form.php?action=formation_save',
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function() {
            $('.formationSection > div').slideToggle();
        }
    });
```

But when , in the PHP side in the formation_save file, I do a `$_POST`, PHP returns me NULL.

and when I do also a  `file_get_contents("php://input");`
PHP returns also me NULL

But Why ? How to make it working ?

PHP code

```
<?php

    $postValues = $_POST;
    $phpinput = file_get_contents("php://input");
    
    var_dump($postValues);var_dump($phpinput);
```

Comment: specific which form in formdata like `var formdata = new FormData(#idform);`

Comment: specif  `enctype: 'multipart/form-data',`  too.

Comment: I tested that code and the request looks absolutely fine in the browser console; it uses multipart/form-data as it's supposed to. Can you show your PHP code?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I don't think you need to specify form id unless you wanna captured that form's fields

Comment: @swadhwa i don't understand why append all input instead of use `formdata(form)` and append just image.

Comment: Again, the code works fine; here's the output when I do a test: `array(1) { ["id"]=> string(3) "123" } string(0) ""` (I used a single textual input and a file, which would be in $_FILES)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini yes, that is understandably the correct way to do it tho.

Comment: Since you say "in the formation save file", just to be sure: your file is supposed to be called `form.php` and you should use `if ($_GET['action'] == "formation_save") { .. }`. I assume that's what you have?